# Extracting bigrams with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

How do I split an entire text consisting of only letters into bigrams.

For example:

odd even

```
od -> de
dd -> ev
```

This is what I have so far but it does not produce the desired result.

```
[some source] | tail -n +30 | sed 's/[^A-Za-z\n]//g' | sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\([A-Za-z]\)\([A-Za-z]\)\([A-Za-z]\)\([A-Za-z]\)\{\0,1\}/\1\2 -> \3\4, \2\3 -> \4\5, /g' | sed 's/,/,\n/g'
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired result format: `od` produces `de`? Bigrams of the entire string would be in this order (assuming whitespace characters are not legal members of the bigrams): `(o,d) (d,d) (d,e) (e,v) (v,e) (e,n)`. Considering they don't need to have parantheses and commas for easy parsing, you could have: `od dd de ev ve en`. Is this going to be done only using `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next `sed` script:

Content of `infile`:

```
odd even
one test        of              bigrams
```

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## Inside square brackets there are two characters: space and tab.
## The instruction deletes them of the line.
s/[     ]*//g

## Label 'b'.
:b

## Copy line to 'hold space'.
h

## Get first bigram.
s/\(..\)\(..\).*/\1 -> \2/

## If last substitution succeed, continue to label 'a'.
ta

## Here last substitution failed: It means that line has less than four
## characters to extract a bigram, so read next line.
b

## Label 'a'
:a

## Print.
p

## Copy 'hold space' into 'pattern space'.
g

## Delete first character.
s/^.//

## Goto label 'b' to repeat loop.
tb
```

Run the script:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

Result:

```
od -> de
dd -> ev
de -> ve
ev -> en
on -> et
ne -> te
et -> es
te -> st
es -> to
st -> of
to -> fb
of -> bi
fb -> ig
bi -> gr
ig -> ra
gr -> am
ra -> ms
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "od\ndd\nde\nve" | 
sed '1{x;s/^/oddevenodd/;x};G;/^\(..\)\n.*\1\(..\).*/s//\1 -> \2/'
od -> de
dd -> ev
de -> ve
ve -> no
```

Is this what you mean?

```
echo -e "odd even\nthis and that" | 
sed 's/ //g;s/^\(..\)\(.*\)/\1\2\1/;h;:a;s/^\(..\)\(..\).*/\1 -> \2/p;g;/^..../{s/^..//;h;ba};d'
od -> de
de -> ve
ve -> no
th -> is
is -> an
an -> dt
dt -> ha
ha -> tt
```